# How can I express that two values are not equal to eachother?

Tags: java, if-statement, equals, boolean-expression

Is there a method similar to `equals()` that expresses "not equal to"?

An example of what I am trying to accomplish is below:

```
if (secondaryPassword.equals(initialPassword)) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You've successfully completed the program.");
} else {
    secondaryPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Your passwords do not match. Please enter you password again."); 
}
```

I am trying to find something that will not require me to use `if ( a != c)`.

Comment: I don't get how using something like `!string.equals(..)` (which is the method 'notEquals') will help you not use a OR.

Comment: I meant to type `(a != b)`. My bad. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just put a '!' in front of the boolean expression

Answer (score 33):

"Not equals" can be expressed with the "not" operator `!` and the standard `.equals`.

```
if (a.equals(b)) // a equals b
if (!a.equals(b)) // a not equal to b
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (!secondaryPassword.equals(initialPassword))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class implements comparable, you could also do

```
int compRes = a.compareTo(b);
if(compRes < 0 || compRes > 0)
    System.out.println("not equal");
else
    System.out.println("equal);
```

doesn't use a `!`, though not particularly useful, or readable....